# Return price as an object/variable using Interactive Brokers TWS API - Python

Tags: python, tws

As the title indicates, I am trying to get the price of a given security from TWS API and use it as a variable in my program elsewhere. The below code (straight from one of Interactive Broker's tutorials) will run and print the price out on the screen but I haven't been able to alter it in a way that works in getting to create a variable/object that contains the price. The code also only works about once in every ten tries, if there is something I'm doing wrong there, please let me know.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.ticktype import TickTypeEnum


class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print('Error: ', reqId, ' ', errorCode, ' ', errorString)

    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
            print('Tick Price. Ticker Id:', reqId, 'tickType:', TickTypeEnum.to_str(tickType), 
            'Price:', price, end=' ')


def main():
    app = TestApp()

    app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, 0)

    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = 'AAPL'
    contract.secType = 'STK'
    contract.currency = 'USD'
    contract.exchange = 'SMART'
    
    app.reqMarketDataType(1)
    app.reqMktData(1, contract, '', False, False, [])

    app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program doesn't take into account the asynchronous nature of the api.

```
#here you are asking to connect, you must wait for a connection
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, 0)

contract...
# you may not have a connection and you're not listeneing for responses yet.
app.reqMarketDataType(1)
app.reqMktData(1, contract, '', False, False, [])

# here is where you start listening for responses, that's what run() does
app.run()
```

I would write it like this

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.ticktype import TickTypeEnum
from ibapi.common import *

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        # here you can add variables to the TestApp class, just use self.var in the class
        self.last = 0;
        
    # ib suggests waiting for this response to know that you have a connection
    def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):    
        self.reqMarketDataType(MarketDataTypeEnum.REALTIME) # or DELAYED
        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = "AAPL"
        contract.secType = "STK"
        contract.currency = "USD"
        contract.exchange = "SMART"
        self.reqMktData(1, contract, "", False, False, None)

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print('Error: ', reqId, ' ', errorCode, ' ', errorString)

    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
            print('Tick Price. Ticker Id:', reqId, 'tickType:', TickTypeEnum.to_str(tickType), 
            'Price:', price)
            if tickType == TickTypeEnum.LAST or tickType == TickTypeEnum.DELAYED_LAST :
                self.last = price;
                print("disconnecting")
                self.disconnect() # just for testing, normally the program would do something

def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)
    app.run() # this blocks the program until disconnect()
    print("app.last:", app.last) # now you refer to the variable by class.var

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Brian, I appreciate the quick reply. This works great and does exactly what I needed.